# Rails sanitize method adding double quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-injection, sanitize

I am using `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize` method to avoid **SQL injection attacks**.

My issue is wherever I sanitize user input the output is returned with adding extra double quotes before the single quotes in the beginning of string and after the single quotes in the end of the string.

example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize("Test")
=> "'Test'"
```

I was expecting it to return `"Test"` or `'Test'`. why it is returning `"'Test'"` ??

Thanks,
Sanjay Salunkhe

Comment: I've tried your code and it returns as what you expects, `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize("Test")` returns **'Test'**

Comment: No its not working for me. my rails version is 4.1.7 and ruby version is ruby 2.0.0p598

Comment: @SanjaySalunkhe actually its deprecated, check DOC: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/sanitize/class

Answer (score 3):

`sanitize` is working as expected. The problem here is the Rails console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize("Test")
=> "'Test'"
puts ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize("Test")
'Test'
=> nil
```

The console automatically wraps the result with extra "".

Comment: i don't want to print the value . i want to store it in a variable. if i am storing this value in a variable then it is not working.

Comment: I understand that. It was just to show you the return value of `sanitize` is **'Test'** in this example, and not **Test** as one could imagine. This token **'Test'** is correctly escaped as far as SQL servers go.

Another way to verify that is to do this `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize('Test').split('')`. It will show you all the individual characters of your return string.

Answer (score 0):

[`ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/sanitize/class) has been deprecated and it internally calls [`quote`](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Generators/Actions/quote) method:

```
def quote(value)
  return value.inspect unless value.is_a? String
   if value.include?("'")
      value.inspect
   else
     "'#{value}'"
   end
end
```

Thanks to the comments of @jeffdill2

The purpose of `sanitize` method is to add extra single quotes which would break injected SQL statements if there is any.

Comment: I am using sanitize method to prevent sql injection. removing double quotes will work but is this a good approach to use sanitize method to avoid sql injection??

Comment: I don't know why you need `ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize` but you can do something like this to avoid sql injection. **Example:**  This `User.where("id = #{params[:id]}")` should be `User.where("id = ?", params[:id] )` to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: yes you are right. but sometimes i am executing plain sql query that time i have to use sanitize method.

Comment: Using `remove("'")` negates the purpose of using `sanitize()`.

Comment: @jeffdill2 here `remove` is added to just remove the extra quotes from the string, can you please give me an insight **how did it negates the purpose of using `sanitize()`** ?

Comment: Because the quotes that `santize()` adds are a crucial part of how it prevents SQL injection. Without them, you're still inserting raw text, not quote-qualified text, into your query. Yes, `sanitize()` would still remove nefarious HTML tags – `javascript:`, etc. – but without quoting the text, you're still open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @jeffdill2 thanks for the explanation and I have updated my answer. Hope it clarifies the meaning!